# Use a HTML/Javascript form to create outlook email with embedded images using ActiveXObject

Tags: javascript, html, outlook-2007, activexobject

Afternoon All,

I need to be able to embed images into an outlook email via a html form that runs locally on a workstation desktop. There is no internet access. All machines are Windows with Outlook 2007.
The below code works great for creating emails with a HTML body, but I also need to embed images into the email that are stored on the local documents folder of the user.

Is there a way to find out what directory path is to the users documents folder?
And how can I embed the images so they show within the body content NOT as an attachment?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function OpenOutlookDoc()
{
try
{

var outlookApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
var nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace("MAPI");
mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(6);
mailItem = mailFolder.Items.add('IPM.Note.FormA');
mailItem.Subject="a subject test";
mailItem.To = document.getElementById("name").value;
mailItem.HTMLBody = document.getElementById("name").value + " " + "<b>bold</b>";
mailItem.display (0); 
}
catch(e)
{
alert(e);
// act on any error that you get
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var outlookApp = new ActiveXObject("Outlook.Application");
var nameSpace = outlookApp.getNameSpace("MAPI");
mailFolder = nameSpace.getDefaultFolder(6);
mailItem = mailFolder.Items.add('IPM.Note.FormA');
mailItem.Subject="a subject test";
mailItem.To = document.getElementById("name").value;
mailItem.Attachments.Add("C:\pictest.jpg");
 mailItem.HTMLBody = "<html><p>This is a picture.</p><img src='cid:pictest.jpg' height=480 width=360>";
mailItem.display (0);
```